# correlated subquery within CTE is not synchronised

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, correlated-subquery

Given the query below,

The issue that I am facing is the following

```
 WHERE
      initial_categories.id = categories.id
```

In the condition above, the `categories.id` should be synchronised with the outer categories.id.

This works when I use `sqlite` ( the `categories.id` is synchronised with the outer value)

BUT, when I use `mysql` for some reason the `categories.id` in the condition, takes only the first value from the outer `categories.id` and it doesn't change after that ( in other words is not synchronised ), and more specifically the `categories.id` has always the value `1` inside the CTE.

I can't figure out what is the issue. Any thoughts ?

```
SELECT
   *,
   (
      SELECT
         id 
      FROM
         threads 
      WHERE
         threads.category_id IN 
         (
            WITH recursive recursive_categories AS 
            (
               SELECT
                  initial_categories.id 
               FROM
                  categories AS initial_categories 
               WHERE
                  initial_categories.id = categories.id 
               UNION ALL
               SELECT
                  remaining_categories.id 
               FROM
                  recursive_categories 
                  JOIN
                     categories AS remaining_categories 
                     ON recursive_categories.id = remaining_categories.parent_id 
            )
            SELECT
               id 
            FROM
               recursive_categories 
         )
      ORDER BY
         updated_at DESC limit 1
   )
   AS recently_active_thread_id 
FROM
   "categories" 
WHERE
   "parent_id" IS NULL 
   AND "categories"."group_category_id" IN 
   (
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7,
      8
   )
```

------ purpose of the query -------

I have the tables

`categories`

```
- id
- parent_id
- title
```

`threads`

```
- id
- category_id
- title
```

Now a `category` can have `sub-categories` which are found using the `parent_id` from the `categories` table.

A `category` that has `sub-categories` is not associated directly with a `thread`

Only a `category` that doesn't have `sub-categories` is associated with `threads`

To give an example

```
Computer -> MAC -> MacBook 
Computer -> WINDOWS -> HP
```

In the example above, only the `categories` `MacBook` and `HP` are associated with `threads`

What I am trying to achieve with the query below is to find the **latest thread** among all `sub-categories` for a given **parent category**

To continue with the aforementioned example, I want to find the latest thread that is associated indirectly with the `Computer` category

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that `categories.id` will be the *outer* categories id you can alias the outer `categories`, something like:

```
FROM categories AS outer_categories
```

and the WHERE clause would be:

```
WHERE initial_categories.id = outer_categories.id
```

So change to:

```
SELECT outer_categories.*,
   (
      SELECT id 
      FROM threads 
      WHERE category_id IN (
            WITH recursive recursive_categories AS (
               SELECT initial_categories.id 
               FROM categories AS initial_categories 
               WHERE initial_categories.id = outer_categories.id 
               UNION ALL
               SELECT remaining_categories.id 
               FROM recursive_categories JOIN categories AS remaining_categories 
               ON recursive_categories.id = remaining_categories.parent_id 
            )
            SELECT id FROM recursive_categories 
         )
      ORDER BY updated_at DESC limit 1
   ) AS recently_active_thread_id 
FROM categories AS outer_categories
WHERE outer_categories.parent_id IS NULL 
  AND outer_categories.group_category_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that didn't work, which kind of makes sense because, if the ```categories.id``` was completely unknown, I think it would give an error. But in my case it just doesn't change value

Comment: and it is also weird that this doesn't happen with ```sqlite```

Comment: @OrestisuRic In the WHERE clause `outer_categories.id` for sure refers to the outer categories table, which is what you want. Also don't rely on SQLite code because it has its own special features. So working code in SQLite is not always working in other databases too.

Comment: I'm using ```sqlite``` only for testing purposes and in this particular case it seems to be working on ```sqlite``` and not in ```mysql```. Also even before using the alias ```outer_catefories``` I think that it was still referring to the outer_categories since I used an alias every time I used the ```categories``` within the subquery.

Comment: However, the problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

I created a function which returns the **latest thread id**.

Essentially, I moved the query and subquery into a function and it works

```
CREATE FUNCTION `recently_active_thread`(category_id INT) RETURNS int
BEGIN 
  DECLARE recentThreadId INT;
  SELECT id 
  INTO recentThreadId
  FROM   threads 
  WHERE  threads.category_id IN ( WITH recursive recursive_categories AS 
                                 ( 
                                        SELECT initial_categories.id 
                                        FROM   categories AS initial_categories 
                                        WHERE  initial_categories.id=category_id 
                                        UNION ALL 
                                        SELECT remaining_categories.id 
                                        FROM   recursive_categories 
                                        JOIN   categories AS remaining_categories 
                                        ON     recursive_categories.id=remaining_categories.parent_id )
                          SELECT   id 
                          FROM     recursive_categories ) 
ORDER BY updated_at DESC limit 1; 
return recentThreadId;
end
```

And then I call the function in the select statement

```
SELECT outer_categories.*, recently_active_thread(outer_categories.id)
FROM categories AS outer_categories
WHERE outer_categories.parent_id IS NULL 
  AND outer_categories.group_category_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```